# Can I set different fonts for different languages in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, configuration, indentation

I prefer proportional fonts, but these are not viable for code styles relying on alignment with spaces like in Clojure. So I would like to keep my current font for most languages in IntelliJ Idea and set a different (monospaced) font for just Clojure. Is it possible?